# Как отменить перерисовку функциональных компонентов?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

у меня есть глобальное хранилище наподобие Redux. C помощью контекста я раздаю состояние на все приложение:

```js
<StoreProvider>
    <Router>
        <Fragment>
          <Header />
          <Main>
              <Literature />
          </Main>
        </Fragment>
    </Router>
</StoreProvider>
```

В компоненту Literature есть input который меняет это состояние. Из-за этого все приложение начинает перерисовываться. Как мне отменить перерисовку если компонент не зависит от состояния. Пытался использовать React.memo, но он сравнивает пропсы. Например, компонент Header не принимает вообще пропсы.

Comment: `shouldComponentUpdate`, а вообще в функциональные компоненты не нужно передавать сложные пропсы, аля объекты, массив и так далее

Comment: shouldComponentUpdate используют в классах, а не в функциональных компонентах. Структура состояние довольно проста. там нету глубокой вложенности.

Comment: а как вы поняли, что у вас все перерисовывается?

Comment: включил флаг highlight updates. У всех компонентов появляются рамки

Comment: `update` не означает `redraw` .

Comment: highlight updates означает rerender компонента